# mysql_query() error in PHP form

Tags: php, sql, forms

So I use to program in PHP my own way and then someone told me to start using his way.
This of course caused me to do a few mistakes.
So this is the code:

```
<?php 
function SignIn()
{
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','avi1574','test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['user_w'])) 
{ 
$query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `Users` where `User` = '$_POST[user_w]' AND  Password = '$_POST[pass_w]'") or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
if(!empty($row['User']) AND !empty($row['Password'])){
     $_SESSION['user_w'] = $row['Password']; 
echo "Logged in."; 
}
else{ 
echo "Sorry, wrong password."; } }}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     SignIn(); 
} 
?>
<h1>My login page</h1>
<form action="tsql.php" method="POST" >
<input type="text" name="user_w" size="20"></input>
<input type="password" name="pass_w" size="20"></input>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Sumbit</button>
</form>
```

When I submit the form I get the following error:
`Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in test-main/htdocs/test/tsql.php on line 10`

Line 10 is: `$query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM`Users`where`User`= '$_POST[user_w]' AND  Password = '$_POST[pass_w]'") or die(mysql_error());`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are mixing `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions, just change them all to `mysqli_`

Comment: use mysqli only and then run your sql and log the error.

Comment: @user3932619 I don't know "your way" but "someone's way" is not good practice.

First of all you must separate UI (HTML) and logic (PHP). Then and only about what concerns to database, help yourself and read about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

If you're aware of SQL Injection let me say that your source code is vulnerable

Comment: always use single or double qoutes to the key in $_POST or $_GET.

Answer (score 1):

Many bad practice in there, let me point out a few things.

```
$_POST[pass_w]
```

This doesn't work as `pass_w` is not a constant. See [this article](http://blog.flowl.info/2014/cant-put-array-variables-right-string/). You must use quotes for the index: `$_POST['pass_w']`.

You are open to SQL injection and you should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

You also can't mix `mysqli` and `mysql`. **Don't** use `mysql_` functions, they are not as secure and deprecated.

To your error message, you are simply trying to put a resource into `mysql_query` where function expects the query as a string, like `SELECT...`. You must switch the parameters.

When doing selects for password and username, ensure case sensitivity by using `BINARY`
and put  `LIMIT 1` at the end, to ensure only 1 record in return.

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE BINARY username = ... LIMIT 1
```

Also use some hashing function (not sha1 and not md5 please :-) for the password, with salt!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the function you're using from `mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM`Users`where`User`= '$_POST[user_w]' AND  Password = '$_POST[pass_w]'")` to `mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM`Users`where`User`= '$_POST[user_w]' AND  Password = '$_POST[pass_w]'")`
(`mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query`).

While you're at it, you should also probably change `mysql_fetch_array()` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, for two reasons:

1. you should use mysql and not mysqli since its deprecated
2. you're accessing `$row`'s associative array keys, so you need the function to return associative array whild mysqli_fetch_array() returns numeric keys.

Answer (score 0):

Many bugs
`User` = '$_POST[user_w]' should be `User` = ".$_POST['user_w']."

Here is some links which may be helpful

about mysql functions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

about mysqli functions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Mysql functions is the original function while Mysqli is the extension of Mysql functions

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `Users` where User = '".$_POST['user_w']."' AND  Password = '".$_POST['pass_w']."'");
```

but read the solution from DanFromGermany, because I gonna point out the same mistake, but as he already mention so no point,

Thanks